# string manipulation in python using list

Tags: python, string, list, string-matching

I have some tweets which contain some shorthand text like ur,bcz etc. I am using dictionary to map the correct words.  I know we cannot mutate strings in python. So after replacing the with correct word, i am storing a copy in a new list. Its working. I am facing issue if any tweet have more than one shorthand text.

My code is replacing one word at a time. How can i replace words multiple times in a single string. 
Here is my code

```
# some sample tweets
tweet = ['stats is gr8', 'india is grt bcz it is colourfull', 'i like you','your movie is grt', 'i hate ur book of hatred' ]

short_text={
    "bcz" : "because",
    "ur" : "your",
    "grt" : "great",
    "gr8" : "great",
    "u" : "you"
        }

import re

def find_word(text,search):
    result = re.findall('\\b'+search+'\\b',text,flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(result) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


corrected_tweets=list()
for i in tweet:
    tweettoken=i.split()
    for short_word in short_text:
        print("current iteration")
        for tok in tweettoken:
            if(find_word(tok,short_word)):
                print(tok)
                print(i)
                newi = i.replace(tok,short_text[short_word])
                corrected_tweets.append(newi)       
            print(newi)
```

my output is

```
['stats is great',
 'india is grt because it is colourfull',
 'india is great bcz it is colourfull',
 'your movie is great',
 'i hate your book of hatred']
```

What I need is tweet 2 and 3 should be appended once with all correction. I am new to python. Any help will be great.

Comment: Do you need an entry for every corrected version? like *'india is grt bcz it is colourfull'* it append twice because there are 2 short words.

Comment: I need a single entry will all the correct spells. So there should be only one entry with both correction.

Comment: In your if condition if find_word() return true you append it your corrected_tweets list. but it should be done when all the short_word corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a regex function on word boundary, fetching the replacement in the dictionary (with default to original word, so returns the same word if not found)

```
tweet = ['stats is gr8', 'india is grt bcz it is colourfull', 'i like you','your movie is grt', 'i hate ur book of hatred' ]

short_text={
    "bcz" : "because",
    "ur" : "your",
    "grt" : "great",
    "gr8" : "great",
    "u" : "you"
        }

import re

changed = [re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b",lambda m:short_text.get(m.group(1),m.group(1)),x) for x in tweet]
```

result:

```
['stats is great', 'india is great because it is colourfull', 'i like you', 'your movie is great', 'i hate your book of hatred']
```

this approach is very fast because it has `O(1)` lookup for each word (doesn't depend on the length of the dictionary)

Advantage of re+word boundary vs `str.split` is that it works when words are separated with punctuation as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comp for this:

```
[' '.join(short_text.get(s, s) for s in new_str.split()) for new_str in tweet]
```

#### result:

```
In [1]: tweet = ['stats is gr8', 'india is grt bcz it is colourfull', 'i like you','your movie is grt', 'i hate ur book of hatred' ]
   ...:

In [2]: short_text={
   ...:     "bcz" : "because",
   ...:     "ur" : "your",
   ...:     "grt" : "great",
   ...:     "gr8" : "great",
   ...:     "u" : "you"
   ...:         }

In [4]: [' '.join(short_text.get(s, s) for s in new_str.split()) for new_str in tweet]
Out[4]:
['stats is great',
 'india is great because it is colourfull',
 'i like you',
 'your movie is great',
 'i hate your book of hatred']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

```
tweet = ['stats is gr8', 'india is grt bcz it is colourfull', 'i like you','your movie is grt', 'i hate ur book of hatred' ]

short_text={
    "bcz" : "because",
    "ur" : "your",
    "grt" : "great",
    "gr8" : "great",
    "u" : "you"
        }

for j,i in enumerate(tweet):
    data=i.split()
    for index_np,value in enumerate(data):
        if value in short_text:
            data[index_np]=short_text[value]

    tweet[j]=" ".join(data)

print(tweet)
```

output:

```
['stats is great', 'india is great because it is colourfull', 'i like you', 'your movie is great', 'i hate your book of hatred']
```